# Send metadata within an action to the reducer in redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, antd

I have a component which builds onto the `Select` component from `Ant Design` https://ant.design/components/select/

```
<SomeComponent
onSelect = { this.props.handleSelect }
onDeselect = { this.props.handleDeselect }
selectionList = { valuesList }
value = { values }/>
```

`onSelect` triggeres the action `this.props.handleSelect`

```
export function handleSelect(value) {
    return dispatch => {
        dispatch(actionCreator(HANDLE_SELECT, value));
    }
}
```

That actions goes into the `reducer`

```
case HANDLE_SELECT: {
    const newValues = value_select(state, action);
        return {
            ...state,
            find: {
                ...state.a, 
                values: newValues
            }
        }
 }
```

Finally, `value_select` is called to do all the magic

```
export const value_select = function(state, action) {
    ...

    const newData = {
    XYZ: action.payload
    }
    return newData
}
```

This brings me to my question.
Is it possible to send further `metadata` with the `action`? Imagine I use the component `<SomeComponent.../>` several times. I would not know which of the rendered components triggered the `action` when the `onSelect` is fired. 
If I want to process the information in `value_select = function(state, action) {...` later, I want to know which `component` caused the `action` to process my data properly. I need to set `XYZ` in `value_select()` dynamically, depending on which `<SomeComponent.../>` caused the `action`. `action.payload` only gives me what is saved in `value` in `<SomeComponent.../>`, nothing more.
Is there a way to send some more information with the `onSelect` or is that bad practice and I would need an `action` for each `component <SomeComponent.../>` anyway?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Absolutely.  It's your action and your reducer, you can attach any information you want to it.

The most common approach for structuring an action is the [Flux Standard Action](https://github.com/acdlite/flux-standard-action) approach, which expects your actions to look like `{type, payload, meta, error}` but it's really up to you what you put into your actions.

For some more ideas, you might want to read through the [Structuring Reducers - Reusing Reducer Logic](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/reducers/ReusingReducerLogic.html) section of the Redux docs.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. You are writing that is completely up to me "what I put into the action/reducers". What I still cannot get my head around is how I would get additional information into handleSelect(value), depending on what is clicked. That must happen somewhere in the component, because I have that component several times. Hence, the component must give the information, that it is clicked (a unique information for each component)

Comment: If you have multiple instances of the component all trying to use the same action creator, it's still up to you what parameters those components pass to the action creator.  For example, `onClick={() => handleSelect(value, someId)}`.  Then, modify the action creator to include that ID in the action.